# warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Tags: c, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm curious, I'm programming in *C* on PuTTy, does anyone know how I can get rid of this warning?

> warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] realloc(strp->data, nbytes);

```
                        ^
```

Relevant code to the line it wants to 'warn' me about:

```
         //If the previously allocated size is > 0 then we can reallocate
         //otherwise we have to make a new allocation in memory
         if(strp->length > 0)
         {
           realloc(strp->data, nbytes);
         }
         else
         {
           *strp = kstralloc(nbytes);
         }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Getting rid of the warning is easy: Don't ignore the return value of `realloc()`. Maybe you should read the documentation.

Comment: PuTTy is not an IDE. What do you mean with "I'm programming in C on PuTTy"? And how to get rid of the warning is simple: follow the implicit advice of the warning. What exactly do you not understand??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to call realloc is something like this:

```
tmp = realloc(strp->data, nbytes);
if (tmp == NULL) {
    // your realloc didn't work and strp->data still points to the
    // the original location
    return EMEMORY;
}
strp->data = tmp;
```

Comment: ...to be followed by `strp->data = tmp`

Comment: Right.  And definitely, never do strp->data = realloc(strp->data, nbytes);

Comment: on modern systems, can `realloc` return `NULL` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre any memory allocation can theoretically return NULL.  This can happen when the system is very busy, or you've asked for a huge segment of memory.

Comment: yes, but I read on this site that you could allocate a lot of memory, the system returns an address, but when you use it, you get segfault :) so much for being optimistic :)

Comment: also, you could add to your answer that not considering the return of `realloc` may _seem_ to work until the memory segment is moved to another location.