# Listing file names in a dir and putting them in a string - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I'm using the code below to list files in a directory and then put them in one long string called `filename_list`. The logic is

1. allocate a zero-character, null-terminated char* using strdup("") before the loop
2. increase its size in each iteration using realloc() to do this which preserves the existing contents. I work out how long the new buffer is by adding the old length to the length of the filename.
3. I append the filename to the buffer using strcat().

It works ok until it tries to call realloc() for the final filename which causes a seg fault.

Would anybody know what I am doing wrong? Would it be caused by not being enough room for the length of the final 0?

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *filename_list;

int main(void)
{
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir("/home/johnbrady/binary_test");

  char *start = "";
  filename_list = strdup(start); //allocate a zero-character null-terminated char* to begin with
  int filename_list_length;

  filename_list_length = strlen(filename_list); //get length of filename list length
  printf("size of filename list length is %d\n", filename_list_length); //print size of filename list length 

  if (d)
  {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {

      printf("\n***************************************************\n");
      printf("Getting next file\n");
      int filename_length = strlen(dir->d_name); //get length of the filename
      filename_list_length = strlen(filename_list); //get length of filename
      printf("The value of filename list length is now %d\n", filename_list_length);
      printf("\nthe length of the next filename is %d\n", filename_length);
      printf("The file name is: %s\n", dir->d_name);

      printf("\nresize the memory block for the file name list to be %d\n", filename_length + filename_list_length);
      realloc(filename_list, filename_length + filename_list_length); //reallocate size to accomodate new filename 

      strcat(filename_list,dir->d_name); //append new filename to existing one
      printf("The filename list is now %s\n", filename_list);     
      filename_list_length = strlen(filename_list); //get length of filename
      printf("size of filename list length is now%d\n", filename_list_length);
    }

    closedir(d);
  }


  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `realloc(filename_list, filename_length + filename_list_length);` => `filename_list = realloc(filename_list, filename_length + filename_list_length);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn\_unused\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190326/warning-ignoring-return-value-of-realloc-declared-with-attribute-warn-unused)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you or your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assign the return value of [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) (**Return Value**:
A pointer to the reallocated memory). That's a common mistake when using this function.

Change this:

```
realloc(filename_list, filename_length + filename_list_length);
```

to this:

```
filename_list = realloc(filename_list, filename_length + filename_list_length);
```

---

If you had compiled with warnings enabled, you would have been warned by your friend, the compiler:

> warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] realloc(strp->data, nbytes);

Comment: not really @articsol, I did the same mistake the other day, you are welcome!

Comment: now with your gold badge you could dupehammer this triplicate right ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hmm I am not sure. Since we knew what's wrong and knew what to look for. artic sol on the other hand didn't have a clue. I mean how could he search for the other question? I am not sure...{Damn, with great power, comes great responsibility}.